# Flowchart Iterating through List

Tags: python, flowchart

Let say I have a list l

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

To iterate through the list,

```
for i in l:
    # <some function>
```

My problem is how should I represet it in a flowchart? Should I use i as index? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Flowcharts are rather miserable for loops

Here is the usual way to do it (from http://etutorials.org/Programming/visual-c-sharp/Part+I+Introducing+Microsoft+Visual+C+.NET/Chapter+5+Flow+of+Control/Building+Loops+Using+Iteration+Statements/)

[image]

#### Flowcharts work best for branching workflows with lots of "ifs"

As you progress, you are getting into smaller and smaller subsets of the overall chart.

They *can* work for looping, of the type of `while do` or `do while`, because these inherently tell you to jump back to a point (or skip over a block).

But for looping controlled by a variable, it's ugly, I'm afraid.

In your specific case, you could use these terms:

##### Initialization:

- Set `index` to 0

##### Conditional expression

- Is #`index` item still within the list? i.e. is `index` < `len(list)`?
- If false, arrow down to end
- If true, continue to "Controlled statement"

##### Controlled statement

- `<Some function>`

##### Iteration statement

- Increment `index`
- Go back to "Conditional expression"

Comment: In Python, at least, it's possible to convert an arbitrary `for` loop into an equivalent `while` loop. I could have sworn this is in the documentation somewhere, but I can't locate it at the moment.

Comment: I'm still confused,  what shoulf I set for initialization anx the iteration statement? Using the example above, should I initialize i = 0 and iteration statement will be i+=1? But then how should I controll it ? I understand how to design flowchart for looping over range of numbers but not loops that iterate through the list.

Comment: Does the extra explanation help you fit to your case? It is no different from looping over numbers. You just increment the index. When you want to read the element from the list, you just look in your list at the `#index`th element. Natural for us oldies used to machine code and other horrors, but I hope you find it baffling, because I hope you have been brought up in healthier, higher-level programming!

Comment: I understand it now. Basically for the flowchart just iterate through the list with i as its index and increment i with one. Thanks a lot for the source and additional explanation!

Comment: Yes it is really terrible trying to display like a flowchart. Don't do it. (Unless forced by a teacher e.g. as a punishment for talking in class, etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am taking a programming concept and design course at my foundation program otw to cs degree. We are asked to design and develop program as our assignment with both coding and flowchart. Love coding (although sometimes can be tough for me as beginner) but I really hate drawing flowcharts for the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just in terms of the title, your question is how do you represent it in the flow chart? Whether i is an index,

That's how you represent the for loop,

In general, you have to have a loop initialization condition, a loop judgment, a loop condition change, and i doesn't mean index

So for loops might not be very easy to understand in python, because it doesn't have that, and it might make you wonder why you're using for directly, and you might even wonder if you're going through the underlying index,

Then you need to say that python's for loop causes problems,

python everything is object,

What we call a for loop is actually a foreach loop

Let's see if we're using an index,

Let's do this with a while loop

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

index = 0
while index < len(num_list):
    print(num_list[index])
    index += 1
```

```
num_set = {1, 2, 3, 4}

index = 0
while index < len(num_set):
    print(num_set[index])
    index += 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(num_set[index])
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

The for loop is aimed at an iterable form

So what you really need to describe is this iterable type, which python implements